# Best way to handle static reference data in an application (MVVM)

Tags: java, database, jpa, mvvm, constants

Let's say I have an application allowing **participants** to register and then **pay** for a service. I have to handle a **payment status**.

Using the database, I would distinguish **reference data** from **master data** by creating 2 tables :

```
---------------------------------------------       -----------------
PARTICIPANT                                         PAYMENT_STATUS
---------------------------------------------       -----------------
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    PAYMENT_STATUS_ID       ID  NAME
1   John        McClane     1                       1   paid
2   Lara        Croft       2                       2   not paid
3   Marty       McFly       1                       3   waiting
4   Ellen       Ripley      3                       -----------------
---------------------------------------------
```

As in my application I need :

- to **initialize** the payment status to *"not paid"* when a participant registers
- to have a **list** for admins to be able to manually change the status.

I have to create all the **MVVM** stack (classes and methods).

I was wondering if it is **acceptable** to simply use a "constants" class instead of storing data into the **database**, so all the code would become :

```
//AppConstants.java
public static final String PAYMENT_STATUS_VALIDATED = "paid";
public static final String PAYMENT_STATUS_NOT_VALIDATED = "not paid";
public static final String PAYMENT_STATUS_WAITING = "waiting";
public static final List<String> PAYMENT_STATUS_LIST = Arrays.asList(
     PAYMENT_STATUS_VALIDATED,
     PAYMENT_STATUS_NOT_VALIDATED,
     PAYMENT_STATUS_WAITING
);

//AdminVm.java
public List<PaymentStatus> getPaymentStatusList() {
     return AppContants.PAYMENT_STATUS_LIST
}

//RegisterVm.java
public void register() {
     Participant newPart = new Participant();
     newPart.setPaymentStatus(AppContants.PAYMENT_STATUS_NOT_PAID));
}
```

Instead of :

```
//PaymentStatus
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_status")
public class PaymentStatus {
    [...]
}

//PaymentStatusManager
public List<PaymentStatus> getAll() {
    return paymentStatusDao.getAll();
}

public PaymentStatus getPaymentStatusByName(String str) {
    return paymentStatusDao.getPaymentStatusByName(str);
}

//PaymentStatusDao
public PaymentStatus getPaymentStatusByName(String str);
public List<PaymentStatus> getAll();

//PaymentStatusDaoImpl
public PaymentStatus getPaymentStatusByName(String str) {
    String queryString = "SELECT p FROM PaymentStatus p WHERE p.text = :str";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter("str", str);
    if (query.getResultList().size() > 0) {
        return (PaymentStatus) query.getResultList().get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public List<PaymentStatus> getAll() {
    [...]
}

//AppConstants.java
public static final String PAYMENT_STATUS_NOT_VALIDATED = "not paid";

//AdminVm.java
public List<PaymentStatus> getPaymentStatusList() {
     return paymentStatusMgr.getAll();
}

//RegisterVm.java
private PaymentStatusManager paymentStatusMgr;
[...]
public void register() {
    Participant newPart = new Participant();
    newPart.setPaymentStatus(paymentStatusMgr.getPaymentStatusByName(AppContants.STATUS_PAYMENT_NOT_PAID));
}
```

It avoids all the **MVVM** stack, less code, better performances (no DB access, less network transfer).

And even with database solution it would still be **dependent** on the code as I have to initialize the value. So I don't get a big advantage in terms of maintainability?

What do you think?

Comment: Does Java have enums?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry... But it is more about the concept, is this considered a bad practice compared to database storage? I have a lot of "status" or other reference data.